# Is it possible to nest a ui-view in another ui-view using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a post ui-view in which I would like to nest another comment ui-view **within the same state** (app). All views have the same controller as well.

How will I target a ui-view (comment inside the post ui-view) without using a child state. A child state would require a user to navigate to that state to view comments, I would like the posts and comments to visible as soon as a user navigates to the home page.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<div ui-view="post" ng-repeat="post in posts">

</div>


<!-- posts.html -->
 <div class="post">
     <p>{{post.body}}</p>
     <div ui-view="comment" ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
     </div>
 </div>

<!-- comments.html -->
<div class="comment" >
    <p>{{comment.body}}</p>
</div>


app.config(['$stateProvider',
  function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state("app", {
        url: '/',
        views: {
           'posts@app': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/posts.html',
                    controller: 'PostController',
            }
        }
      })
  }
]);
```

Comment: Did you google "ui router nested views"? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views

Comment: @DavidSpence, I did. I can't find a nesting of views similar to my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Per [ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views), you can utilize multiple views on the same page or nested views.  What you have there is 2 views on the same page, in which you'll need multiple [named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

If you're wanting a view inside a view, you'll want to use the first link, where you can just use `ui-view`, but you have to put the second `ui-view` on the template of the first `ui-view`.

You can't put another `ui-view` inside the div of another `ui-view`.  Your best option is to give them id's and then style them with css.  Or if you're wanting, say, comments on a post, you'll actually want to use the second one where you create the post template, and then put a `ui-view` on that page for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.config(['$stateProvider',
  function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state("app", {
        url: '/',
        views: {
           'posts@app': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/posts.html',
                    controller: 'PostController',
            }
        }
.state("app.comments", {
        url: '/comments',
        views: {
           'comments@app': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/comments.html',
                    controller: 'CommentsController',
            }
        }
      })
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but please check my updated question to get a better idea about what I'm shooting for.

Answer (score 0):

From your sample you just want to reuse the comment html repeatedly within the post html. In this case you would just use ng-include to include a partial (the comment html). See ng-include in the angularjs docs. Nothing to do with ui-router.

Your ui-view maps to the post html and includes your controller. Your post html includes the comment html repeatedly.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this will work. Another idea is to use 1 state and with child states that don't change the parent states url. Then every time the home page is visited it navigates to the appropriate child state.